# set up environment for python2.7, but "pip install ." gave error of the package requires a different python: 2.7.18 not in '>=3.7,<4.0'

Tags: package-management, python-2.7

(with Windows11 and currently using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

https://github.com/ding-lab/CharGer/blob/7d7d2911b89261fa5dceea6395a5d188a82757f2/README.md

I followed the instruction and created environment as mentioned

while in the CharGer environment: $python -V

gave out Python 2.7.18 :: Anaconda, Inc.

but while in CharGer folder and $ pip install .

it returns "ERROR: Package u'charger-0.6.0b1' requires a different Python: 2.7.18 not in '>/3.7,<4.0'

Comment: Please specify the version of your operating system.

Comment: Windows 11
doing this in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Please add the information to your actual question: use "Edit".